# How to extract pdf text from BT and ET section line by line and how to decode Tj block to unicode in pdfbox

Tags: extract, cdi, pdfbox, decoding

As the title, I have the special requirement to extract text line by line or block by block of BT and ET.
below is the pdf content, I tried PDFTextstripper class, but it is not what I want,
so any one has the solution to resolve the problem?
I wanna parse this : `[ (=\324Z\016) ] TJ.......`

[image]

this is my pdf: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63353043/docu.pdf

below is my code:

```
  enter coList<Object> tokens = pages.get(0).getContents().getStream().getStreamTokens();


            tokens.forEach(s->{
                if(s instanceof COSString){
                    System.out.print(s.toString());
                }
```

but, I get thoes:
COSString{&Ð}COSString{O6}COSString{&³}COSString{p»}COSString{6±}COSString{˛¨}COSString{+^}COSString{+·}COSString{˚©}COSString{9}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{˛¨}COSString{Fœ}COSString{0ł}COSString{Q¯}COSString{#”}COSString{˛¨}COSString{+^}COSString{(Ï}COSString{˚©}COSString{9}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{Zo}COSString{#°}COSString{˜}COSString{p»}COSString{#Š}COSString{5×}COSString{,
}COSString{:É}COSString{(Ù}COSString{4ÿ}COSString{ä}COSString{_Á}COSString{˛¨}COSString{:É}COSString{p»}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{#p}COSString{/F}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{F,}COSString{_N}COSString{!}COSString{9»}COSString{]˘}COSString{!¢}COSString{˜.}COSString{p»}COSString{#°}COSString{˜}COSString{#p}COSString{<:}COSString{Zo}COSString{1¸}COSString{ä}COSString{˚~}COSString{F³}COSString{!Ø}COSString{]Š}COSString{`2}COSString{6±}COSString{˛¨}COSString{gî}COSString{+·}COSString{9á}COSString{XS}COSString{hP}COSString{h[}COSString{˜º}COSString{˚.}COSString{p»}COSString{5d}COSString{5×}COSString{]˘}COSString{_ö}COSString{#c}COSString{2˚}COSString{]˜}COSString{+·}COSString{9á}COSString{p»}COSString{@b}COSString{˚.}COSString{eÚ}COSString{;
}COSString{!5}COSString{:É}COSString{XS}COSString{hP}COSString{h[}COSString{˜º}COSString{p»}COSString{B!}COSString{&Ø}COSString{`,}COSString{/F}COSString{^r}COSString{˛²}COSString{2&}COSString{˜.}COSString{N}COSString{*ø}COSString{˜.}COSString{&¢}COSString{+B}COSString{+·}COSString{9á}COSString{ä}COSString{ZX}COSString{˚}COSString{˛µ}COSString{6«}COSString{0ł}COSString{!Ø}COSString{p»}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{F,}COSString{Q±}COSString{"}}COSString{XS}COSString{&Ð}COSString{_N}COSString{!}COSString{9»}COSString{˛²}COSString{F,}COSString{(Ï}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{F³}COSString{/?}COSString{˛¨}COSString{=­}COSString{˚4}COSString{9}COSString{p»}COSString{;}COSString{5×}COSString{_Á}COSString{˜³}COSString{@É}COSString{0·}COSString{F,}COSString{Q±}COSString{"}}COSString{p»}COSString{1û}COSString{"}}COSString{˚.}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{p»}COSString{#°}COSString{˜}COSString{Lê}COSString{5d}COSString{Zo}COSString{1¸}COSString{"G}COSString{˚.}COSString{ä}COSString{&Ð}COSString{Kå}COSString{Yª}COSString{#°}COSString{#´}COSString{5ê}COSString{p»}COSString{(Ï}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{ZR}COSString{pÉ}COSString{p„}COSString{˜}COSString{G“}COSString{_û}COSString{%v}COSString{pÎ}COSString{1û}COSString{"}}COSString{1¹}COSString{F,}COSString{˛µ}COSString{5×}COSString{˜}COSString{2˚}COSString{]˜}COSString{+·}COSString{9á}COSString{p»}COSString{O´}COSString{5×}COSString{@b}COSString{˚.}COSString{+·}COSString{9á}COSString{p»}COSString{˜}COSString{]y}COSString{/0}COSString{`}COSString{2§}COSString{˚.}COSString{˛¨}COSString{8E}COSString{N}COSString{*ø}COSString{22}COSString{++}COSString{&¢}COSString{+B}COSString{)%}COSString{ä}COSString{&Ð}COSString{!Í}COSString{˚b}COSString{f¨}COSString{Y)}COSString{.}COSString{"Q}COSString{5ê}COSString{p»}COSString{)*}COSString{7D}COSString{˛¨}COSString{˜³}COSString{˚b}COSString{P¥}COSString{&Ð}COSString{!Í}COSString{˚b}COSString{˛µ}COSString{G“}COSString{0m}COSString{F,}COSString{0m}COSString{<i}COSString{˛³}COSString{p»}COSString{;ﬁ}COSString{˛µ}COSString{BÞ}COSString{\}COSString{F,}COSString{BO}COSString{Bˆ}COSString{Q™}COSString{-Ž}COSString{F,}COSString{!Ñ}COSString{Fr}COSString{p»}COSString{$™}COSString{/½}COSString{BO}COSString{Bˆ}COSString{F,}COSString{#™}COSString{5×}COSString{˛¨}COSString{nƒ}COSString{nƒ}COSString{p»}COSString{˚}COSString{5×}COSString{f‰}COSString{P¥}COSString{#Š}COSString{\\}COSString{F,}COSString{p°}COSString{1¹}COSString{<:}COSString{6±}COSString{C®}COSString{DÙ}COSString{˛µ}COSString{Q¯}COSString{_Á}COSString{9Ë}COSString{F,}COSString{˚b}COSString{#°}COSString{˜}COSString{p»}COSString{_Á}COSString{9Ë}COSString{F,}COSString{˚b}COSString{˚}COSString{<:}COSString{6±}COSString{C®}COSString{DÙ}COSString{˛µ}COSString{Cˆ}COSString{/?}COSString{1¸}COSString{"G}COSString{p°}COSString{p“}COSString{/4}COSString{˜.}COSString{p»}COSString{+·}COSString{O©}COSString{en}COSString{F,}COSString{˚3}COSString{9}COSString{7D}COSString{@Þ}COSString{DÙ}COSString{;}COSString{T`}COSString{T`}COSString{5“}COSString{˛²}COSString{p»}COSString{]2}COSString{ }COSString{]2}COSString{(Ï}COSString{p°}COSString{:}COSString{6«}COSString{Må}COSString{&Ð}COSString{˛µ}COSString{M;}COSString{0·}COSString{e;}COSString{O«}COSString{aw}COSString{˚b}COSString{F,}COSString{FÇ}COSString{ZH}

Comment: Maybe the PrintTextLocations.java example is for you?

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by *extract text line by line or block by block of BT and ET*: PDFBox (just like most other text extractors, too) simply walks the content stream and in particular extracts one BT/ET text block after the other. Could you show an example what output you expect in case of your sample document?

Comment: @mkl sorry,my English is no good,I mean that can I though some method to parse the already encoded text?

I though PDFBox to get the page's InputStreamAsStrimg,but I get the CosString that are [ (=\324Z\016) ] TJ......., It had encoded, can I though some method to reduction the text??

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks you a lot for adjustment my question. 謝謝你

Comment: I don't understand either - another possibility is that you're intererested in the PDFStreamParser, which parses the content stream. To see an example, have a look at the RemoveAllText.java example in the source download. You'll get tokens with operators and parameters.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr sorry......, I had added my source code and result, may you help me??

Comment: If you want only the parameters of the text operators, then you need to check the operators like in the RemoveAllText.java example. If you want to convert the stuff in the parameter, then I'm coming back to the PrintTextLocations.java. It does not just show the text locations but also unicode. If you want to decode parameters like PDFBox itself, then you should have a look at the source code, at PDFTextStreamEngine. Make a copy of this and make the changes you need, e.g. write your own ShowText() and ShowTextAdjusted(). Look at PrintTextLocations to understand how to call the PDFBox "engine".

Comment: Btw I suspect you're using 1.8. Don't do that if you're a newbie, use the latest version, which is 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

*(If this wasn't so long, it would have been more appropriate as a comment to the question instead of as an answer. But comments are too limited.)*

The OP in his question shows that he essentially wants to parse the content stream of e.g. a page and extract the strings drawn in a legible form. He attempts this by simply taking the tokens in the content stream and looking at the `COSString` instances in there:

```
List<Object> tokens = pages.get(0).getContents().getStream().getStreamTokens();

tokens.forEach(s->{
    if (s instanceof COSString) {
        System.out.print(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the output looks like a mess.

### Why do the string values in the content stream look so messy?

The reason for this is that those `COSString` instances represent the PDF string objects as they are, and that there is no single encoding of PDF string objects in content streams, not even a limitation to a few standardized ones.

The encoding of a string completely depends on the definition of the font currently active when the string drawing instruction in question is executed.

Fonts in PDFs can be defined to use either some standard encoding or a custom one and it is very common, in particular in case of embedded font subsets, to use custom encodings mapping constructed similar to this:

- the code 1 to the glyph of this font which is first used on the page,
- the code 2 on the second glyph of this font on the page which is not identical to the first,
- the code three to the third glyph of this font on the page not identical to either of the first two,
- etc...

Obviously there is no good to conjecture the meaning of string bytes for such encodings.

Thus, when parsing the content stream, you have to keep track of the current font and look up the meaning of each byte (or multi byte sequence!) of a `COSString` in the definition of that current font in the resource dictionary of the current page.

### How to map those messy bytes using the current font definition?

The encoding of a PDF font might have to be determined in different ways.

- There may be a **ToUnicode** map in the font definition which shows you which bytes to map to which character.
- Otherwise the encoding may be a standard encoding like **MacRomanEncoding** or **WinAnsiEncoding** in which case one has to bring along the mapping table oneself (they are printed in the PDF specification).
- Otherwise the encoding might be based on such a standard encoding but deviations are given by a mapping from codes to *names* of glyphs. If certain standard names are used, the character can be derived from that name. These names are listed in another document.
- Otherwise some **CIDSystemInfo** entry may point to yet another standard Registry and Ordering from which to derive a mapping table specified in other documents.
- Otherwise the font program itself may include usable mappings to Unicode.
- Otherwise ???

### Any pitfalls to evade?

The *current font* is a PDF graphics state attribute. Thus, one does not only have to remember the most recently set font but also consider the effects of operations changing the whole graphics state, in particular the save-graphics-state and restore-graphics-state operations which push the current graphics state onto a stack or pop it there-from.

### How can PDF libraries help you?

PDF libraries which support you in text extraction can do so by doing all the heavy lifting for you,

- parsing the content stream,
- keeping track of the graphics state,
- determining the encoding of the current font,
- translating any drawn PDF strings using that encoding,

and only forward the resulting characters and some extra data (current position on the page, text drawing orientation, font and font size, colors, and other effects) to you.

In case of PDFBox 2.0.x, this is what the `PDFTextStreamEngine` class does for you: you only have to override its `processTextPosition` method to which PDFBox forwards those enriched character information in the `TextPosition` parameter. As you also want to know the starts and ends of the **BT** ... **ET** text object envelopes, you also have to override `beginText` and `endText`.

The class `PDFTextStripper` is based on that class and collects and sorts those character information bits to build a string containing the page text which it eventually returns.

In PDFBox 1.8.x there was a very similar `PDFTextStripper` class but the base methods were not that properly separated in a base class, everything was somewhat more intermingled and it was harder to implement one's own extraction ways.

(In other PDF libraries there are similar constructs, sometimes event based like in PDFBox, sometimes as a collected sequence of `Textposition`-like objects.)